# Get report for multiple websites

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm looking for a way to get an automated report with my analytics data on (or 1 per website) made for multiple websites. I know there are ways to have a report made for a individual website but I'm looking to get it automatically done for multiple sites. Is there anything currently out there that can do this or am I stuck manually doing it 1 by 1?

Thanks!

Comment: So for example say once per month I could press a button and have a document made up with data about all my websites

Comment: Use the Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-On for Google Spreadsheets - you can configure multiple reports (and set triggers to have them updated in intervals, so you don't even have to press a button).  https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on